# Overwrite vendor module file

Tags: magento2, vendor

How can we overwrite this file?

```
/var/www/html/magento/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/src/Emogrifier.php

<?php 
namespace Pelago;

use Pelago\Emogrifier\Utilities\CssConcatenator;

class Emogrifier
{
public function emogrify()
    {
        $this->assertExistenceOfHtml();

        $this->process();

        return $this->render();
    }

protected function process()
    {
        $this->clearAllCaches();
        $this->purgeVisitedNodes();
     ...
     ....
     ....
     ...
    }
}
```

Module don't have **registration.php** and **etc/module.xml** file.

want to change in **process()** function.

[image]

Comment: Please let me know which class you want to override so I can check accordingly for you.

Comment: @TarunBhalodia, Please review, i have update question.

Comment: Have you tried implementing code given in answers here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this suits your answer

[Override vendor/magento/module-catalog-search for Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/338104/override-vendor-magento-module-catalog-search-for-magento-2)

If you need more help please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Pelago\Emogrifier\Utilities\CssConcatenator\Emogrifier" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Utilities\CssConcatenator\EmogrifierOverrrite" />
</config>
```

[FOR MORE CLICK HERE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91990/magento-2-training-overriding-a-core-class)

Answer (score 0):

**I don't have the exact same Magento version as you but I have tried to write the below code based on your namespace and class name.**

Follow these steps and let me know if it works for you.

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/registration.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Tarun_StackOverflow', __DIR__);
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Tarun_StackOverflow" />
</config>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Pelago\Emogrifier" type="Tarun\Stackoverflow\Utilities\Emogrifier" />
</config>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/Utilities/Emogrifier.php**

```
<?php
namespace Tarun\StackOverflow\Utilities;

use Pelago\Emogrifier as ThirdPartyEmogrifier;

class Emogrifier extends ThirdPartyEmogrifier
{
    ...........
    ...........
}
```

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code in **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Pelago\Emogrifier\Utilities\CssConcatenator\Emogrifier" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Utilities\CssConcatenator\EmogrifierOverrrite" />
</config>
```